# Invalid Procedure or Call Using cell.Value

Tags: excel, vba, string

I wish to replace the current text in each selected cell with a substring which consists of everything left of the first instance of `(` minus one space to the left. For example: `Bob Smith (Director)` becomes `Bob Smith`.

Unfortunately, I get an invalid procedure or call error on fourth line (`cell.Value =`). Would like to keep this in VBA, as it's one of many actions within a larger VBA subroutine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:A4000").Select
For Each cell In Selection
    position = InStr(cell.Value, "(") - 1
    cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, position)
Next cell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If InStr does not find the substring it returns zero. So you are trying to get Left(strin, -1), Check if the `(` was found before making the call to Left.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:A4000").Select

For Each cell In Selection

    position = InStr(cell.Value, "(") - 1
    if position > 0 then
        cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, position)
    end if

Next cell
```

Comment: Thank you! Ah, yes, my problem was that some of the data did not have the "(" . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it work perfectly when i tested it

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Position As Integer

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:A4000")

For Each cell In rng
Position = InStr(cell.Value, "(") - 2
cell.Value = CStr(Left(cell.Value, Position))
Next cell
```

Comment: Thank you -- this is great! The problem was exactly what user11217663 guessed -- some of the data did not have the string I was looking for and that caused an error. Thanks again!